# Uploading data into the memory using regex expression in Kotlin

Tags: regex, kotlin

This question is about two forms of regex: "\w+" and "\W+", which are used to store string data into two different data structures, namely List and Sequence.

In the first scenario, "\w+" along with the function findAll(contents), which is a member function of the regex class, will store the individual words in a data structure as a sequence. The individual words are stored in the memory where first is pointing to the next and so on. In contrast, the second scenario uses "\W+" along with a higher-order function to store the same data into a list of String type.

The code block provides further elaboration on the two scenarios. Although the node of data in the first scenario is storing the word and the range where the word is located in the contents, the individual word is stored within a separate cell within a list in the second scenario.

The query is about how the compiler is retaining the indexes of each word range.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val contents = "I saw a fox in the wood"

    // region 1. build sequence of all words within the contents!
    val regexSqu = """\w+""".toRegex()
    val wordsSqu = regexSqu.findAll(contents)
    wordsSqu.forEach { word -> // word is the address of word rather that the value
        println("${word.range}: ${word.value}")
    }
    // endregion

    // region 2. build list of all words
    val regexList = """\W+""".toRegex()
    val wordsList = regexList.split(contents).filter { it.isNotBlank() }
    println(wordsList)

    wordsSqu.forEach { word ->
        println("${word.range}: ${word.value}")
    }
    // endregion
}
```

Comment: What sort of help do you need? I'm having trouble identifying a question in this post.

Comment: List is of type String. each cell is retaining a single string extracted from the text using regex. However, where and how the range is stored therein? Please note, obtaining the range is applicable in the case of List<String> as shown in the code block under region 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range isn't stored anywhere. `String`s don't have any concept of "where it came from".

---

**Further Explanation**

The difference in the two functions is in the return type. [findAll](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/find-all.html) returns `Sequence<MatchResult>`, and [split](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/split.html) returns `List<String>`. The important part isn't `Sequence` vs `List`, it's `MatchResult` vs `String`. [`MatchResult`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-match-result/) is an object that includes information about the matches found, including the what value was found and where it was found.

As far as why, with `findAll` you're basically saying *"go find everything that matches and report it back to me"*. With `split` on the other hand, you're saying *"go find everything that matches, **discard** it, and give me back what's left"*. So there is no match to report a range back. That's why you use `\W+` which is the opposite of `\w+`.